# Cannot Install ASP.NET MVC 3 RC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Web platform installer gives me a success message but MVC 3 is not present on my system - in VS or in control panel.

I donwload the installer which tells me

```
OS Version = 6.0.6000, Platform 2
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9]OS Description = Vista - x86 Ultimate Edition
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9] OS Version Information
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9] Environment details: ...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9]CommandLine = c:\temp\ext46220\setup.exe
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9]TimeZone = GMT Standard Time
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9]Initial LCID = 1033
[12/10/2010, 11:50:9] Environment details
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10]Loading localized engine data for language 1033 from c:\temp\ext46220\1033\LocalizedData.xml
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10] Entering Function: LocalizedData::CreateLocalizedData...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10] exiting function/method
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10] succeeded
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10] Entering Function: EngineData::CreateEngineData...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10]Current SetupVersion = 1.0
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10]SetupVersion specified in ParameterInfo.xml is '1.0'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:10]Adding Item type "Exe", local path VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path AspNetWebPages.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path AspNetMVC3.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:11]Adding Item type "MSI", local path NuGet.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]No ProcessBlock element
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]No ServiceBlock element
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]Disabled CommandLineSwitch added: createlayout
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12] exiting function/method
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12] succeeded
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12] MaintenanceMode determination: evaluating EnterMaintenanceModeIf...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]evaluating EnterMaintenanceModeIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]returning false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12] MaintenanceMode determination evaluates to 'not in maintenance mode'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12] Operation Type: ...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:12]Operation: Installing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] Operation Type
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] Package details: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]Package Name = Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]Package Version = 3.0.11029.0
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] Package details
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] User Experience Data Collection Policy: ...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] User Experience Data Collection Policy
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] Entering Function: UiDataT::CreateUiDataT...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]Loading file - c:\temp\ext46220\UiInfo.xml
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]Add to schema collection schema file - c:\temp\ext46220\SetupUi.xsd
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]Successfuly found file c:\temp\ext46220\1033\SetupResources.dll
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]Successfuly found file c:\temp\ext46220\Strings.xml
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] exiting function/method
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] succeeded
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] Global Block Checks: Checking for global blockers...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] BlockIf: This product requires the Microsoft .NET 4 Framework. Please install the missing component, then try to install this product again....
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]This product requires the Microsoft .NET 4 Framework. Please install the missing component, then try to install this product again.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]evaluating BlockIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] GreaterThan: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version contains '4.0.30319'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] GreaterThan evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] BlockIf evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:13] Global Block Checks no blocking conditions found
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]OpenFileMapping fails with last error: 6
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]The handle to the section is Null
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]OpenFileMapping fails with last error: 6
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]The handle to the section is Null
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]Successfuly found file c:\temp\ext46220\1033\EULA.rtf
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14] Applicability for Installing: evaluating each item...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:14]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe - available but not verified yet
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {66634F8D-F647-46F7-B6C9-24926E60F8D2} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi - available but not verified yet
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {BAC485C7-6069-41A8-BCE5-7CF9A73B2233} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi - available but not verified yet
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi - not applicable
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {452755D0-6E46-4A66-997B-AA6DFEAEE96B} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi - available but not verified yet
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {224675ED-3FB1-4917-86F6-BD6E158CE958} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi - available but not verified yet
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:15]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi - not applicable
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Determining state: of c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {A111E3EC-EE69-4AFB-B669-FAA308E138CD} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Determining state of c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi - available but not verified yet
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]returning true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {66634F8D-F647-46F7-B6C9-24926E60F8D2} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:16]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {BAC485C7-6069-41A8-BCE5-7CF9A73B2233} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]returning true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {452755D0-6E46-4A66-997B-AA6DFEAEE96B} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {224675ED-3FB1-4917-86F6-BD6E158CE958} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating ApplicableIf:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version contains '30319.01'
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]all numeric characters - canonicalizing
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]RegKeyValue: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version does NOT exist.
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]returning BoolWhenNonExistent's value: false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] LessThanOrEqualTo evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Or evaluated to true
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists: evaluating...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]MsiGetProductInfo with product code {A111E3EC-EE69-4AFB-B669-FAA308E138CD} found no matches
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Exists evaluated to false
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Applicability for Installing determination is complete
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Applicability Result Count: ...
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]Number of applicable items: 6
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17] Applicability Result Count
[12/10/2010, 11:50:17]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:50:38]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action: System Requirement Checks...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action: Disk space check for items being downloaded...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]Drive:[C:\] Bytes Needed:[16681560] Bytes Available:[139290734592]
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action: Enumerating incompatible processes...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]No Blocking Processes
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action: Enumerating incompatible services...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]No Blocking Services
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]Launching Download and Install operations simultaneously.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action: Downloading and/or Verifying Items...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe
[12/10/2010, 11:53:33] c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe: Verifying signature for VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe - Signature verified successfully for VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe Signature verified successfully for VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Signature verification succeeded for VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]File c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe, locked for install.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe Success
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi: Verifying signature for AspNetWebPages.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi - Signature verified successfully for AspNetWebPages.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi Signature verified successfully for AspNetWebPages.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Signature verification succeeded for AspNetWebPages.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]File c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi, locked for install.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPages.msi Success
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi: Verifying signature for AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi - Signature verified successfully for AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi Signature verified successfully for AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Signature verification succeeded for AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]File c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi, locked for install.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi Success
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi: Verifying signature for AspNetMVC3.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi - Signature verified successfully for AspNetMVC3.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi Signature verified successfully for AspNetMVC3.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Signature verification succeeded for AspNetMVC3.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]File c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi, locked for install.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3.msi Success
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]evaluating IsPresent:
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]returning false
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi: Verifying signature for AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Starting install of item 'VS10-KB2385361-x86' at tickCount = 2362993
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi - Signature verified successfully for AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38] c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi Signature verified successfully for AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Signature verification succeeded for AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]File c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi, locked for install.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi Success
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38] c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi: Verifying signature for NuGet.msi...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi - Signature verified successfully for NuGet.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38] c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi Signature verified successfully for NuGet.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Signature verification succeeded for NuGet.msi
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]File c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi, locked for install.
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Verifying Digital Signatures: c:\temp\ext46220\NuGet.msi Success
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows was NOT visible, taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows was NOT visible, taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:54:10]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:54:33]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:57:38]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 12:3:19]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 12:5:24]WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]calling PerformAction on an installing performer
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32] Action: Performing actions on all Items...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:32]Wait for Item (VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe) to be available
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe is now available to install
[12/10/2010, 11:53:37]Creating new Performer for Exe item
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Created new ExePerformer for Exe item
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38] Action: Performing Action on Exe at c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe...
[12/10/2010, 11:53:38]Launching CreateProcess with command line = VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe /q
[12/10/2010, 12:11:12]c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe - Exe installer does not provide a log file name
[12/10/2010, 12:11:12]Exe (c:\temp\ext46220\VS10-KB2385361-x86.exe) failed with 0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation. .
[12/10/2010, 12:11:12]PerformOperation on exe returned exit code 1603 (translates to HRESULT = 0x80070643)
[12/10/2010, 12:11:12] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 12:11:12]Error 1603 is mapped to Custom Error:
[12/10/2010, 12:11:13]OnFailureBehavior for this item is to Rollback.
[12/10/2010, 12:11:13] Action complete
[12/10/2010, 12:11:13]Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:21:01).
```

Comment: Did you install the preview release of the future .NET that includes the Async Await features? They're not able to both be installed.

Comment: Yeah, I'v taken down all mvc 3, NuGet and update stuff that causes conflict as well

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help, look also in comments http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2010/12/mvc-3-rc2-install-error-0x80070643.html

Answer (score 3):

This KB article sorted me out (even though I had never installed pre-release SDKs).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531566

See the bit about taking the \ off the paths, uninstalling ASP.NET Web Pages and reinstalling MVC 3. Must note that ASP.NET Web Pages didn't come back in Control Panel so I might be missing it, which is fine since I don't dig on classic ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2010/12/mvc-3-rc2-install-error-0x80070643.html

This certainly Helped me get on the right track.

i had the a similar error message when trying to install the release version.

I fixed it by unpacking the AspNetMVC3Setup then running the vs10-kb2483190-x86.msi

It then asked for a dialog to my Visual Studio Disk which i pointed to. Takes a while to install but everything works after that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a problem installing MVC3 (as I had on one system).  I found that I was able to install after I manually extracted the install then set permissions on the install directory to Everyone - Full Access.

I was then able to run Setup.exe and get MVC 3 (release) installed.