# Orchard CMS - just installed via WPI, gives error 500

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, orchardcms

Pretty much what the title says really, I followed [the instructions](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Default.aspx?Page=Installing-Orchard&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) on the orchard project website to install v0.9 with the web platform installer.
No error whatsoever until I tried to access it with my browser, when I just got an error 500.19

I have issues finding what's wrong with my install as IIS/ASPX error messages are less than explicative (at least compared to apache/PHP), and enabling error logging leads to the creation of 200+ kb XML files where I can't seem to find anything that points me in the right direction for troubleshooting

Any ideas where I might start looking for what's wrong? Even better, any known installer issues with orchard 0.9?

EDIT:

Error given is:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebData' does not
exist in the namespace 'WebMatrix' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Line 25:     using WebMatrix.WebData;
```

So it's missing an assembly - how can it be that it's missing `Webmatrix.Webdata` if the previous line is `using WebMatrix.Data` and it gives no error there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have the exact error message and stack trace. From what little information you gave, I'd guess you have a version of MVC or ASP.NET Web Pages that is incompatible with what this version of Orchard needs. You can either uninstall these and let Orchard load the version it has in its bin directory or install the latest.
Otherwise, please file a bug on CodePlex giving as many details as possible about your configuration and the error you're se

Comment: This made got me look in the right place, and I found out that I had an old prerelease version of MVC 3: I eventually installed the release version and, with some problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409422/cannot-install-asp-net-mvc-3-rc) got it working

Answer (score 1):

The 500.19 Internal Server Error is almost for sure a configuration error.

If you have a look at the error page you can find the exact reference of the error itself.

The error is in the web config file because the xml is not well formed somewhere. I have experienced this error a couple of times but I can't remeber exactly where it was sorry...

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem on my machine by installing the MVC 3 Releae Candidate 2 via the Web Plattform Installer (3). Hope that solve your problem too.

Best Regards,
Fabian Raetz

Answer (score 0):

Get the Orchard ZIP file from their site, extract it and open the solution in Visual Studio 2010 or WebMatrix or VS Express and try to run it. You can also run it directly from the folder you extracted it to by using IIS Express.

The installation through Web Platform Installer is broken and it won't work.

[Windows Platform Installer fails during Orchard installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688071/windows-platform-installer-fails-during-orchard-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I solved it by adding IUSR and IIS_IUSR to the list of allowed users for the folders in Explorer Properties->Security->Edit->Add.  I used the default settings (Read & Execute, List, Read) for both users.  Restart the web site in IIS.

I can now see my site and everything appears to be working.  Fingers crossed...

BTW: I did a WPI and used Web Matrix > Run to handle the inital configuration.

If you want to add a theme or module, you'll need to give IIS_IUSR write permissions on the Themes and Modules folders.  After you've finished you changes, make sure you restore the permissions to the more limited settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got today the same error.

I resolved it in 3 simple steps:

**STEP 1. Add Deployable Dependencies**

[image]

**STEP 2. Find _bin_deployableAssemblies folder**

[image]

**STEP 3. Copy files from _bin_deployableAssemblies to your target BIN folder.**

[image]

(Just in case u can copy ALL files u have got there to your target BIN folder.)

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms after installing Orchard 1.8 on Windows 8.1 Pro. I used the web platform installer to add IIS recomended configuration and IIS ASP.Net and IIS ASP. ASP.Net Extensibility. One or more of those fixed it. I know I should have tried one at a time but by then I was getting annoyed. I'm using IIS Express 7.5.

When I installed on IIS 6 it worked on another machine running Windows Server 2008, it worked first time. I think IIS installation has been broken down into smaller pieces and you don't get them all now.