# Windows Platform Installer fails during Orchard installation

Tags: orchardcms

I'm attempting to install Orchard 1.0 on a Windows 7 box. It has only just been released. I downloaded and installed the Windows Platform Installer and attempted to install Orchard. The error message is that the application has stopped working and asks if I want to debug or close the application.

The event log contains a single error:

> The event logging service encountered an error while processing an incoming event published from Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing.

I tried installing MVC3 and it worked without any issues.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: I guess the orchard team aren't on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have located the answer on the Orchard CMS Discussion tab on Codeplex.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=241684

The installation script was missing a reference to a library.  They have now rectified this and have advised that you need to delete the AppData folder.

C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer

Once I did this the WPI orchard cms installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem on a Windows 7 and a Windows Vista SP2 system. 
MVC3 installs without problems and works just fine. Orchard CMS crashes WPI.

Comment: I can confirm that MVC3 installs fine for me too.  The orchard install fails with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Orchard ZIP file from their site, extract it and open the solution in Visual Studio 2010 or WebMatrix or VS Express and try to run it. You can also run it directly from the folder you extracted it to by using IIS Express.

The installation through Web Platform Installer is broken and it won't work.

Comment: Fortunately it appears that it now works.  So the ZIP installation is not required.